# filter any in json datatype in sequelize psql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql, sequelize.js

I need to filter any data into the json datatype field in sequelize postgres.

I tried filter with json,but i need to filter data any.

my tried code is:

```
{
  complaint : 
     {
        "Name":"Baskar", 
        "Mobile": "9095256042", 
        "Address": "Chennai", 
        "Department": "MECH", 
        "Name Of Student": "xyz"
     }
}
{
  'complaint': {
        $contains: Sequelize.cast(`
            {Name:'Baskar'}`, 'jsonb')
       }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. How the object should look after filter?

Comment: i am using sequelize orm with using postgres database, and i want to search any data into the json object  with json datatype field. like normal search bar